# Evaluation of an AST (as a GADT) with arrows as atomic values

Tags: haskell, abstract-syntax-tree, arrows, gadt

The following program type-checks and compiles:

```
import Control.Arrow

data Ns = Na | Nb | Nc | Nd deriving Show

data Net a where
    Uni :: a -> Net a
    Serial :: Net a -> Net a -> Net a
    Branch :: Show a => Net a -> Net (Net a, Net a)

deriving instance Show a => Show (Net a)

eval :: (Arrow a) => Net c -> a b (Net c)
eval (Uni m) = arr (const (Uni m))
eval (Serial m n) = eval m >>> eval n
--eval (Branch m) = eval m &&& eval m

example = Serial (Serial (Uni Na) (Uni Nb)) (Serial (Uni Nc) (Uni Nd))

main = do
    putStrLn $ show (app (eval example, Na))
```

However, when I try to add a case for `eval (Branch m)`, type checking bombs out. Something of type

```
Arrow a => a b (Net d)
```

is expected, but of course the way I have it is

```
Arrow a => a b (c',c'')
```

Does anyone have a suggestion for how to write `eval (Branch m)`?

**EDIT I**

In response to @sabauma comment, I think the type signature for `eval` will have to change, but I'm not sure what it should be.

**EDIT II**

Here's an example of what should happen:

```
branch = Branch example
app (eval branch, Na)
```

should give,

```
Uni (Uni Na,Uni Na)
```

This is what @sabauma 's proposal does.

Comment: Are you sure that the posted code type-checks? Even with the final case commented out, I still get a type error involving the signature you put on `eval`. GHC infers the type `eval :: Arrow a => Net a -> a (Net a) (Net a)`.

Comment: @sabauma I've corrected the type declaration for `eval`. At least, changed it back to the way I had it before trying to add `eval (Branch m)`

Comment: You should definitely add some examples with expected outputs, or further explanation on the semantics. It's very difficult to guess what `eval` should do exactly, given the information you provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is

```
eval :: (Arrow a) => Net c -> a b (Net c)
eval (Uni m)      = arr (const (Uni m))
eval (Serial m n) = eval m >>> eval n
eval (Branch m)   = (eval m &&& eval m) >>> arr Uni
```

I don't know if this has the desired behaviour, but it typechecks and is not
the trivial solution. This lets you get away without changing the type signature.

Comment: This looks right. `eval (Branch (Uni Na))` gives me what I expect, i.e. `Uni (Uni Na,Uni Na)`. I just need to ponder the semantics for a bit.

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be to redifine `Branch` to take two arguments (since *branching* somehow implies that for me):

```
data Net a where
  Uni :: a -> Net a
  Serial :: Net a -> Net a -> Net a
  Branch :: Show a => Net a -> Net a -> Net (Net a, Net a)
```

leading to

```
eval :: (Arrow a) => Net c -> a b (Net c)
eval (Uni m) = arr (const $ Uni m)
eval (Serial m n) = eval m >>> eval n
eval (Branch l r) = (eval l) &&& (eval r) >>> arr (uncurry Branch)
```

But I can't say if this change makes sense for you. You probably should give some explanation how your type would be used.

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm not entirely sure on the purpose of your code, and this might not be what you're after, the following typechecks:

```
eval :: Arrow a => Net c -> a b (Net c)
eval (Uni m)      = arr (const (Uni m)) 
eval (Serial m n) = eval m >>> eval n
eval (Branch m)   = arr (const (Branch m))
```

of course, `arr . const` trivially works for eval, but now I'm almost positive that's not what you wanted.